# Plotting a candlestick with mplfinance

Tags: python, graph, candlestick-chart, mplfinance

I want to plot a candlestick graph with data that keeps getting updated but I'm facing some trouble. So I have successfully used `mplfinance` to plot the candlestick but I can't find a way to clear the plot and update the plot every time new data point gets included.
Currently a new graph gets created every time the new data points get included instead of being updated on one graph.

```
import mplfinance as fplt

df=pd.DataFrame({'time':date_list,'Open':open_price,'High':high_price,'Low':low_price,'Close':close_price})
df.index=date_list

fplt.plot(df,type='candle',title='EUR_USD',ylabel='Price ($)')
```

This code will run everytime the df is updated. I tried `fplt.cla()` and `fplt.clf()` but does not seem to be the correct attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can **update the plot** through the use of the `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation()` function.

In the code below:

- `get_data()` is used to retrieve the latest data from the data source. You can use your own method to retrieve the relevant data.
- the `animation.FuncAnimation()` is responsible for calling the `animate()` function **every 5 minutes**.
- the `animate()` function makes use of the `get_data()` function to retrieve the latest data, and then clears and updates the plot.

If you are using **Jupyter Notebook** or similar, then you may want to add this to the top of your notebook.

```
%matplotlib widget

# %matplotlib widget: requires ipympl: pip install ipympl : https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/
# enables using the interactive features of matplotlib in Jupyter Notebooks, Jupyter Lab, Google Colab, VSCode notebooks, Google Colab
```

### Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import yfinance as yf

def get_data():
    # valid periods: 1d, 5d, 1mo, 3mo, 6mo, 1y, 2y, 5y, 10y, ytd, max
    # valid intervals: 1m, 2m, 5m, 15m, 30m, 60m, 90m, 1h, 1d, 5d, 1wk, 1mo, 3mo
    TICKER = "AAPL"
    df = yf.download(tickers=TICKER, period='5d', interval='5m')
    return df

df = get_data() # download the data to produce the original plot
fig, axes = mpf.plot(df,returnfig=True,volume=True,
                     figsize=(11,8),panel_ratios=(2,1),
                     title='\n\nAAPL',type='candle',mav=(10,20))
ax1 = axes[0]
ax2 = axes[2]

def animate(ival):
    data = get_data()    # retrieve latest data
    ax1.clear()          # clear ax1 and ax2 before replotting the latest data
    ax2.clear()
    mpf.plot(data,ax=ax1,volume=ax2, type='candle',mav=(10,20)) # plot the new data

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=300000)  # update plot every 5 minutes = 300000 secs
mpf.show() # display the plot
```

#### Output:

Here is the first / original plot:

[image: original]

Here is the plot after about 20 minutes:

[image: 20mins]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mplfinance in animation mode.
Here are some links to some examples:

- [mpf growing candle](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/11164790/93549985-7d116c00-f938-11ea-9972-54e9ab850420.gif)
- [mpf_animation_demo1.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/mpf_animation_demo1.py)
- [mpf_animation_demo2.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/mpf_animation_demo2.py)
- [mpf_animation_growingcandle.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/mpf_animation_growingcandle.py)
- [mpf_animation_macd.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/mpf_animation_macd.py)